# Obtener valores de PROMPT con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Buenas noches.

¿Cómo puedo obtener los valores que se han ingresado a través de un prompt de JS para utilizar esos datos en una base de datos?

Tengo entendido que es con AJAX, y he desarrollado este código, pero no realiza ninguna acción sobre el código.

```
<!-- Cambio de la contraseña -->
<button type="submit" class="cambios" onclick="cambioContrasenia()">Cambiar la contraseña</button>

<script>
    function cambioContrasenia(){
        var ctr = prompt("Introduzca la nueva contraseña:");
        console.log(ctr);

        if(ctr != null){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'cambio_pass.php',
                data: {pass: ctr},
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Tengo la librería de JQuery incluida en mi código, pero no realiza ninguna acción.
Y este es el archivo que procesa la información

```
<?php

session_start();

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','2ASIR') or die ("No se puede establecer conexión con el gestor de base de datos");

mysql_select_db('agromarquez') or die ("No se puede establecer conexión con la base de datos");

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$contrasenia = $_GET['pass'];

mysql_query("UPDATE cliente SET contrasenia='$contrasenia' where username='$username'");?>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia el type del button de "submit" a "button" (El submit se usa para enviar datos de un formulario, si quieres ejecutar código en un evento, puedes usar el boton con click.

Y adiciona la libreria de JQuery (en caso de que no esté)

El código quedaría asi:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Cambio de la contraseña -->
<button type="button" class="cambios" onclick="cambioContrasenia()">Cambiar la contraseña</button>

<script>
    function cambioContrasenia(){
        var ctr = prompt("Introduzca la nueva contraseña:");
        console.log(ctr);

        if(ctr != null){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'cambio_pass.php',
                data: {pass: ctr},
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, resolví el problema gracias a tu solución.